# Use the_taxonomies() to create a simple list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm trying to create `<div class="cat-hidden categories"></div>` where `categories` is a list of the categories the current post is posted in.

When just using `the_taxonomies()`, it outputs something like this:

```
<div class="cat-hidden Job Type: &lt;a href='http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/genre/early-career/'&gt;Early-Career&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href='http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/genre/internship/'&gt;Internship&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href='http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/genre/other/'&gt;Other&lt;/a&gt;, and &lt;a href='http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/genre/web-developmentit/'&gt;Web Development/IT&lt;/a&gt;."></div>`
```

Whereas I want it to output something similar to this:

`<div class="cat-hidden Early-Career Internship Web-Development/IT"></div>`

That means I'm going to also have to parse the categories that are outputted because I need `Web Development/IT` to be `Web-Development/IT` or `Web-Development-IT`.  I'm unsure about the `/` being in there because I think CSS doesn't allow a `/`.  That's where you experts come along.

I am very proficient in HTML and CSS, and know some PHP and Wordpress, but I don't know where to begin.

If any more info is needed, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [**`wp_get_post_terms()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to get a list of the post categories and just output the category slug which is already phrased for you, something like this:

```
//in your loop
echo '<div class="cat-hidden';
$cats = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'category');
foreach($cats as $cat){
   echo ' '.$cat->slug;
}
echo '"></div>';
```

Comment: I checked your solution and it works!! Luckily I had found another way too, by doing `<div class="hidden tags <?php $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'jobtype'); foreach($terms as $term){echo $term->slug . ' ';} ?>"></div>`

Comment: I'm unsure what the difference between wp_get_object_terms() and wp_get_post_terms() is, but they both seem to achieve the same thing.  Anyways, thank you for a perfect and quick solution :)

Comment: `wp_get_post_terms` is just a wrapper function for `wp_get_object_terms`, they do both actually do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer up some different approaches ...

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
$terms = ( $terms ) ? wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' ) : array();
$space = !empty( $terms ) ? ' ' : '';
printf( '<div class="cat-hidden%s"></div>', $space . implode( ' ', $terms ) );
```

Another ...

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
$terms = ( $terms ) ? wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' ) : array();
$classes = !empty( $terms ) ? ' ' . implode( ' ', $terms ) : '';
echo "<div class='cat-hidden$classes'></div>";
```

That [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) function is real handy for these kind of things, avoids the need to do any looping yourself..

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives.  I'll save these and use these in the future.